# How to get the sorted 1D array out of a sorted Hashmap?

Tags: java, arrays, api, sorting, twitter

I've already made a Hashmap that contains **String Keys** and **Integer values**. To be more specific, I collected data from twitter API and i sorted my HashMap in descending order according to the number of followers that every user has.

for example:

@jeremy23 : 13.200 followers

@brandonww :10.343

@aviatoy : 6.002
...

The next thing i want to do is to make an 1dimension array that contains only the names of the users (but keeping the order that the sorting gave me). My goal is to make a ranking array with the most following persons.
My problem is that i get my array back but the names is not in the descending order. Can anyone tell me what the problem may be?

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> rankI = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {
        Status t = (Status) tweets.get(i);
        String user = t.getUser().getScreenName(); // take name of user
        int followersCount = t.getUser().getFollowersCount(); // and number of his followers
        rankI.put(user, followersCount); 
    }


    //--------------MAKE A SORTED LIST BY VALUES-------------


    Comparator<String> comparator = new ValueComparator<String, Integer>(rankI);
    TreeMap<String, Integer> result = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(comparator);
    result.putAll(rankI);

    System.out.println(result);




   /--------------Create a sorted array using the map-------

    String [] arr1 = new String[rankI.size()];

        Set entries = rankI.entrySet();
        Iterator entriesIterator = entries.iterator();


    int i = 0;

    while(entriesIterator.hasNext()){

        Map.Entry mapping = (Map.Entry) entriesIterator.next();

        arr1[i] = mapping.getKey().toString();


        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the one line `rankI.keySet().toArray(new String[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

I am new in StackOverflow and i don't know if it's better to delete the question if i found the mistake, but i guess the right thing to do is to keep the post.

I guess the code is ok. The problem is that in the section " Create a sorted array using the map, i don't use the sorted array whose name is **result**. I wrongly use the **rankI** which is not sorted.